# networkx installed but cannot import

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, networkx, network-analysis

I have installed networkx but when I tried to import it in jupyter notebook, an error shown

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-6743fca41c5c> in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
      2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 3 import networkx as nx

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'networkx'
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled it several times but nothing changed.

It worked when I import it in terminal.

```
(base) MacBook-Pro:~ gary$ python
Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 26 2020, 10:32:53) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import networkx
>>> print(networkx.__version__)
2.5
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What did you try in order to install it in Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: @BForce I just installed it use `pip install networkx` How can i install it in Jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write it with an exclamation mark. `! pip install [package_name]`

Comment: I tried. Here’s what i get  `Requirement already satisfied: networkx in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator>=4.3.0 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from networkx) (4.4.2)
`

Comment: Try using "import networkx as nx" again, are you still getting the error?

Comment: You might need to delete ~/Library/Jupyter/kernels check out this post https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2359

Comment: The issue might happen if notebook uses a different python or in a different environment, so check sys.executable and sys.path to make sure that it is using the right one.

Comment: Yeah, try that and then reset the path in the terminal.

Comment: Thank you! I think i found the problem. It is `'/usr/local/bin/python3'` in notebook and `'/opt/anaconda3/bin/python'` when i run sys.executable

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Activate another env and switch back. This works for me.